# IEnumerable in lazy-loading EF

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, lazy-loading

I have two models in EF Code First:

```
public class Book
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public virtual IEnumerable<Page> Pages { get; set; }
}

public class Page
{
 public int Id { get; set; }
 public int BookId { get; set; }
 public Book Book { get; set; }
}
```

When loads a Book model from DB, Pages property is Null. But when replace IEnumerable => ICollection, lazy loading works and Pages fills from DB. How use IEnumerable and lazy loading together?

Comment: I dont think you can as the lazy loader is looking for something to overload and needs an ICollection or derivative such as IList. I dont understand why you would even want to use IEnumerable here instead of ICollection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IEnumerable` is immutable collection which you cannot modify (add or remove). EF does not support this type because internally EF need to modify collection in model.

Use `ICollection` instead, `ICollection` inherits from `IEnumerable` so it not only still get deferred execution (lazy loading) purpose but also has more methods to modify collection.